# jQuery noConflict conflict with replaceWith

Tags: jquery

**My HTML**

```
<div class="item-page">
  <div class="Introduction">
    <div class="FrTxtLoans">
      <h1 class="uppercase"> home-mortgage </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main_content">
    <div class="landing_wrapper"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Question**

What I want to do is remove all the dives around `<div class="landing_wrapper"> </div>`

**My Script**

Im using 
`$('.item-page').replaceWith($('.landing_wrapper'));` and it works like a charm.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dt4Au/) here

**My Issue**

Since I have a MooTools and jQuery conflict on my website, I used `jQuery.noConflict();` at top of my website and renamed

```
$('.item-page').replaceWith($('.landing_wrapper'));
```

with

```
jQuery('.item-page').replaceWith($('.landing_wrapper'));
```

Then the replaceWith stopped working. [jQuery Conflct jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7EadK/)

Can you guys please show me the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code was actually calling the jQuery object twice (the `$`), so in your second example you have to replace both instances of `$` with `jQuery`

```
jQuery('.item-page').replaceWith(jQuery('.landing_wrapper'));
```

Comment: Damn! Damn! Damn!. That fixed it. Thanks man. And sorry for the trouble. Me careless man!

Comment: No problem, I bet you won't miss it again :)